# Signal voltage scaling

Tags: voltage, scaling

I have a linear range control signal from 1.75 V (0%)  to  3.22 V (100%) .

How can I convert this to a 0-5V signal (0-100%)?

I have a single +5V supply with same 0V as control signal.

Comment: Surely this must meet the "no research effort" criteria?

Answer (score 5):

As a starting point, see Bruce Carter's application report titled [Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf) (Texas Instruments, document number SLOA097, Feb. 2002).

For what it's worth, if your power supply voltage is +5 VDC, the task of designing a signal conditioning circuit whose output voltage is precisely 0 V – 5 V is not a straightforward task. The reason is this: an op amp cannot output a voltage that is equal to the voltages at the op amp's power input pins. For example, for an op amp whose power pins are connected to +5 VDC and ground, the op amp's output voltage range does not include +5 VDC nor ground:

$$
0\,\mathrm{VDC} \lt V_{out} \lt +5\,\mathrm{VDC}
$$

So you might find it easier to design a signal conditioning circuit whose output voltage range is, for example, 0.2 V – 4.8 V.

See also:

1. [Single-Supply Op Amp Design Techniques](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf) (Texas Instruments application report, document number SLOA030A, March 2001).
2. J. Heath, "Amplifiers: What do rail-to-rail and single supply mean?" *Analog IC Tips: An EE World Online Resource*, Oct. 10, 2017 [Online]. Available: https://www.analogictips.com/amplifiers-rail-to-rail-single-supply-mean/
3. J. Fischer, "Op Amp in buffer configuration is decreasing output voltage", Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, June 19, 2016 [Online]. Available: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/241540/79842

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, what about rail-to-rail opamps?

Comment: I edited my answer and added two additional references (#2 and #3). In Heath's article, with regard to rail-to-rail op amps she states, "The term 'rail-to-rail' is marketing speak for 'darn close' [to the power supply voltages.] Some advertisements state that they go 'beyond the rails,' but going beyond the rails usually means clipping the signal. The maximum peak-to-peak voltage output swing is one where the waveform is not clipped with reference to a specified level." So rail-to-rail op amps are not exempt from the laws of physics: they also cannot achieve Vout = voltage @ op amp power pin.